# Rails/Devise: Restore session without going through full auth process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm using Devise + ominauth2 to allow users to sign in via different services. If they sign in they get a slightly better experience but if not life still goes on. However I don't see a way with Devise to have a page that allows both authenticated and unauthenticated access.

For example:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def some_action
  end
end
```

In the above controller, some_action is only accessible if the user authenticates. But what I actually want is something more like:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  def some_action
    loadSessionFromCookieIfExists
  end
end
```

Then, I can use user_signed_in? in my views. But this doesn't work because authenticate_user! will redirect them elsewhere. Unless there is an authenticate_if_possible method?

So what I have now, which is really gross is:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, :only=>[:no_auth]

  def action
    do_stuff
    return
  end

  def no_auth
    do_stuff
    return
  end

private

  def do_stuff
    render :template => "action"
  end
end
```

I should add, that omniauth2 doesn't support rememberable out of the gate so it's possible this is all supposed to work just fine and the problem is with omniauth2.

Comment: whats the issue in just removing "before_action :authenticate_user!"?

Comment: Then it never authenticates the user at all.